# Can CiviEvent work with PayPal?

Tags: civievent, paypal

We can't seem to get CiviEvent to work with a user's PayPal account. All works well if the user enters a CC# on our site, but nothing works if the user tries to use their PayPal account. When PayPal sends the user back to our site, the URL fails to resolve, so the user gets "We can't load the requested web page ..."

I can see from the logs that this seems to correspond to a CiviCRM error: Could not find valid value for id. Sure enough, there is no id in the URL we receive from PayPal.

Is there a setting on our end or PayPal's that I'm missing? Some way to get PayPal to use our event id?

I'm now only running the 'Clean-up Temporary Data and Files' once a day, but I still get the error frequently. I'd be grateful for any other suggestions.

Comment: Can you add CiviCRM version your site using>

Comment: Good point: I had been getting the error with CiviCRM 5.9, but upgrading to 5.13 did not make it go away.

Comment: Can you check if you have a schedule job enabled for 'Clean-up Temporary Data and Files' and how often it is executed?

Comment: I just executed  'Clean-up Temporary Data and Files' for the first time. Now, the error seems to be gone!

Comment: This error usually happens when you have cron job that runs this job every hour or minutes. This job clears the session and hence when you come back from paypal CiviCRM doesn't find valid session. So make sure you run this job once in a day

Comment: I'm now only running the 'Clean-up Temporary Data and Files' once a day, but I still get the error frequently. I'd be grateful for any other suggestions.